# Is it possible to use .js.erb file in Rails 6?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I have the following in app/javascripts/custom/test.js.erb

```
export function test(){
  alert('<%= 5 %>');
}
```

But the ERB is not interpreted.

Is it possible to use js.erb like this in Rails 6?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use `js.erb` in webpacker, you would need to install a new package `rails-erb-loader` and also need to configure the webpack loaders.

But no need to worry, webpacker provides built-in rake command to install required packages and configure webpack loaders.

Use:

```rb
bundle exec rails webpacker:install:erb
```

Now just import `app/javascripts/custom/test.js.erb` to `app/javascript/packs/application.js` (packs entry point file). And you are all set!

```js
// app/javascript/packs/application.js

import Rails from "@rails/ujs"
import Turbolinks from "turbolinks"
import * as ActiveStorage from "@rails/activestorage"
import "channels"

Rails.start()
Turbolinks.start()
ActiveStorage.start()

import '../custom/test.js.erb';
```

Reference docs: https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/v5.4.3/docs/integrations.md#erb

Answer (score 2):

It's possible, but you need to make sure that your file is included in the assets pipeline and that it's loaded in your view.

I tested the following example on Rails 6.1:

```rb
# in config/initializers/assets.rb
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w[application.js]

# in app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>

# in app/assets/javascripts/application.js
//= require_tree .

# in app/assets/javascripts/test.js.erb
alert('<%= 5 %>');
```